# Java - equals() and hashCode() implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, hashcode

I have a class PointDensity that is implemented as:

```
import java.sql.Date;

public class PointDensity {

    private int id_place;

    private String algorithm;

    private Date mission_date;

    private int mission_hour;

    private int x;

    private int y;

    public PointDensity(int id_place, String algorithm, Date mission_date, int mission_hour, int x, int y) {

        this.id_place = id_place;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
        this.mission_date = mission_date;
        this.mission_hour = mission_hour;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PointDensity other = (PointDensity) obj;
        return id_place == other.id_place
            && algorithm.equals(other.algorithm) 
            && mission_date.equals(other.mission_date)

            && mission_hour == other.mission_hour
            && x == other.x
            && y== other.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + y;
        result = prime * result + ((algorithm == null) ? 0 : algorithm.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + ((mission_date == null) ? 0 : mission_date.toString().hashCode());
        result = prime * result + mission_hour;
        result = prime * result + id_place;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I read some stuff and get values from a database. And then I want to use a HashMap() in order to store a PointDensity object as key and the times it has been encountered as a value. However, it never finds that the object is the same.

```
    Map<PointDensity, Integer> pointDensities = new HashMap<>();
    while (resultSet.next()){
        PointDensity pointDensity = 
            new PointDensity(
                resultSet.getInt(1), 
                resultSet.getString(2),
                new Date(timestampValues.getLong(i)), 
                new java.util.Date(timestampValues.getLong(i)).getHours(),
                xValues.getInt(i), 
                yValues.getInt(i)
            );  
        if (pointDensities.containsKey(pointDensity)){
            //IT NEVER ENTERS HERE!!!
            System.out.println("exists");
            int times = pointDensities.get(pointDensity);
            pointDensities.replace(pointDensity, times++);
        }else{
            pointDensities.put(pointDensity, 1);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to not reinvent the wheel.  I recommend using the Apache EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder.

Comment: Are you sure that the results you get from the DB are the same?

Comment: Try debugging your `equals` method to pinpoint exactly which condition fails. My guess would be the java.sql.Date comparison.

Comment: If there's an error, it's neither in `equals` nor in `hashCode`, which seem to be correctly implemented. The problem must be in the code that reads data from the DB, I find it suspicious that you're reading the same column many times. What's the `i` variable?

Comment: Lining up the separate clauses in equals would very much aid readability

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem, but `pointDensities.replace(pointDensity, times++);` does nothing. It's the same as `...replace(..., times)`. You probably meant `times+1`.

Comment: I'm with Federico, the code works for me when I try it.  The error must be in the code you haven't shown us, or in the database data.

Comment: By the way: your `hashCode` method checks for nulls in the reference fields, but the equals method doesn't allow them (because you dereference e.g. `algorithm.equals`). You should make them consistent.

Comment: I am also suspicious of the fact you use `Date.toString().hashCode()` in `hashCode`, and `Date.equals` in `equals`. Whilst one might expect comparison using these to be the same, is it possible they aren't? Also, you appear to be using the deprecated `Date.getHours()` method - this is prone to error because of differences in time zone.

Comment: Not directly related, but if possible make the class immutable. JIT might be able to optimize `hashCode()`, or the hash value could be calculated in the constructor and stored as a instance variable and returned from `hashCode()`  (instead of recalculating each time).

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I found where the problem was... When comparing in equals() I was comparing the Date object (timestamp in ms) which obviously is not repeated in my test of data. As I wanted to check the day, not the timestamp, I cahanged it to a String and then works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me, your `hashcode` and `equals` methods seem OK.  The error must be in code you aren't showing us, or in the database data itself.

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
       Map<PointDensity, Integer> pointDensities = new HashMap<>();
       PointDensity pointDensity = new PointDensity( 10, "TEST",
               new Date( 3, 1, 2019 ), new java.util.Date().getHours(),
               42, 24 );
       pointDensities.put( pointDensity, 1 );
       System.out.println( "pointDensity equal to self:"
               + pointDensity.equals( pointDensity ) );
       if( pointDensities.containsKey( pointDensity ) ) {

          //IT NEVER ENTERS HERE!!!
          System.out.println( "exists" );
          int times = pointDensities.get( pointDensity );
          pointDensities.replace( pointDensity, times++ );
       } else {
          pointDensities.put( pointDensity, 1 );
       }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
pointDensity equal to self:true
exists
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Better suited as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, but I wanted to show my code.  If the OP has any comment on the way I tested their code, I'd like to understand their perspective.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I found where the problem was... When comparing in equals() I was comparing the Date object (timestamp in ms) which obviously is not repeated in my test of data. As I wanted to check the day, not the timestamp, I cahanged it to a String and then works fine :)